# ViewController doesn't cover entire screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Does anyone know why my view controller doesn't cover the entire screen?

The view controller was created with a size of "iPhone 4-inch" and I'm running it on the simulator as an iPhone 6s Plus phone. Usually, the view controller auto resizes to whatever iPhone device I select, but it's not doing it anymore. The storyboard in which this view controller was created has "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes" selected which I believe did this for me, but since it's not working I'm not sure what I need to do to get this to work.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make sure you have set a launch storyboard or if you are using launch images make sure you have all the required sizes, otherwise your app will be run in backward compatibility mode

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `Main.storyboard`. **Xcode > File > New > Project...** will get you state of the art new project, with all the bells and whistles.